# Making a shorcut ask for what file to open

Tags: 18.04, files, gnome-terminal, shortcuts

Running Ubuntu 18.04 on a laptop

I want to make a shortcut that when i click it, asks me what file to open(in a certain (pre-established) directory only, not anywhere on the disk) and then opens it for editing using  `gedit fileName &`

Using this command on the terminal works:

```
sh -c "cd ~/example/path ;gnome-terminal; read fileName; gedit $fileName &"
```

My reasoning is it travels to the dir im looking for, opens the terminal there, asks for the fileName, then opens with gedit.

On the shortcut the behavior is a bit different. It travels to the right dir, opens the terminal with that path, then opens a new file.(I assume it creates an untitled file because $fileName is nothing i guess)

Is there a way to do this? The simpler the better.
The purpose of this is to open .c files in the directory without having to travel there and save a bit of time, and learn some commands on the way since i'm fairly new.

Comment: What about a simple "cd  ~/example/path ; gedit"? When gedit lauches, press Ctrl+O and pick your file: de open dialog will by default look into the current directory, which you have set through the cd command. Alternatively, have nautilus open in that folder, and double-click the file you want to open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Atom](https://atom.io/) has support for this by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> which lets you start typing a filename and it will show the closest matches.

Also be aware that `&` only sends a process into the background, when you close the parent process (like your terminal) it will kill all the spawned `gedit` processes. You may want to use `nohup` or `setsid` to avoid that.

Comment: Well, I want to keep the terminal open, since its a .c file, I want to compile it and run it from there without having to close the file every time, so the &

Comment: There are plugins for Atom that will allow you to open a terminal at the bottom. Gedit also has plugins for opening a terminal within the app.

Comment: do you know which and how? the opening the terminal in gedit part i mean

Comment: See https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/2026/how-do-i-open-a-terminal-window-in-gedit